VS Code tab completion behavior more similar to bash/ python/ ipython (among many)
I am going to give this example in Python, but the concept is the same for every language
Suppose one has defined two variables
myvariablewithalongname_1=1
myvariablewithalongname_2=2

In a bash/python/ipython/julia console, if one starts typing myvariablewith and then presses TAB, the text will be completed up to myvariablewithalongname_  and will show the options on how to finish the autocomplete. If there is only one option left, it completes with it.
Moreover, in the console, tab completion also works after a period, so doing np. TAB will show all the options of numpy.
VS Code tab completion works in a different way. In the first case, after typing myvariablewith and clicking TAB it will autocomplete to myvariablewithalongname_1, pressing TAB again will circulate among the options (without ever showing all of them). In VS Code, tab completion does not work after a period, so np. TAB will just add a tabular space.
On the other hand, intellisense has 3 behaviors in vanilla VS Code. It can automatically appear after 100 ms, be triggered by a special character (like a period in Python) or be manually triggered by pressing Ctrl Space.
I don't like the automatic appearance (after 100 ms or after a trigger character) because they are too invasive.
It was pointed out to me that another issue from stack exchange from 5 years ago talked about having TAB completing the beginning of the suggestions that matched. TLDR, does not seem that VS Code developers are interested in that. However, there are some behaviors that should still be possible l, as I describe below.
What I want is pretty simple to describe:
I would like for intellisense and tab completion to seemlesly work together. Intellisense should only be triggered manually and have the following behavior:

if there is only one option, tab completion should complete the option
if there are multiple options, tab completion should display all of them by triggering intellisense
this should work at any place except in places where one is just trying to include a tab, like in the beginning of a line or after a tab.

What I was able to achieve so far:
After a lot of try and error, I figured that including
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
        "when": "atEndOfWord && textInputFocus && !inSnippetMode && !suggestWidgetVisible && config.editor.tabCompletion == 'on'"
    }, 

in my keybinding allows me to get the suggestions to be triggered by TAB without having to press CTRL + Space. What it does not get me is:

it shows me the suggestion box even when there is only one suggestion instead of simply completing the suggestion.
it does not work after a period or any other character. The when condition "atEndOFWord" is what allows me to still maintain the customary behavior of tab in the beginning of a line.

Does anyone have a suggestion?
I tried figuring out by myself, but there is so little documentation. ChatGPT was not really helpfull. I keep imagining that someone else out there must have the same desire as mine, but I don't even know how to look for it.

you aren't using intellisense?

i use the intellisense dropdown, it is way better....  it provides all the options.

As far as I understand, intellisense is what provides the suggestions box. In vanilla VS Code, it can be activated with Ctr + Space, automatically appear after some milliseconds or be triggered by a special character. I don't really like any of these options.

I have edited the comment to make it more clear
